# The necessity of an empty constructor

Tags: java

I've tried running the following code which gives me a `constructor A in class A cannot be applied to given types` error.

```
class A{
    int a;
    A(int b){
        a = b;
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a.a);
}
```

If I remove the c'tor from class `A` however the code runs as expected (and outputs `0`). It seems that if another c'tor exists there is no default c'tor (and an argument less c'tor exists only if it is written). Am I correct?
More importantly, why is this?

Comment: Yes, if a constructor already exists the compiler will not create another. Why? Well, why the compiler should suppose that you always  want a public no-params constructor?

Comment: Read: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/constructor-overloading/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't create a constructor then there is a constructor by default as below

```
public YourClass(){

}
```

But if you create a constructor like below:

```
public YourClass(int x){

}
```

Then you won't have a constructor by default i.e.

```
public YourClass(){
//this won't exist
}
```

So you have to do

```
YourClass anObject = new YourClass(5);//you can do this.
```

And hence you cannot do something like

```
YourClass anObject = new YourClass();//you cannot do this
```

In order to do this you need to create a constructor by yourself as

```
public YourClass(){
//this time you must create this
}
```

For the question **why?**, I doubt there is any reason. This is the way OOP has moved.

Comment: Shouldn't it be accepted? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Once you defined a non-empty constructor, the non-empty conscrutor isn't implicite and you have to explicite it.

```
public A() {
}
```